# PHP simultaneous requests and temporary files

Tags: php

For instance I have a .php that creates a temporary file, and the server receives multiple simultaneous requests for that .php.

How the server is going to schedule the requests?
Are they going to be executed one after the other uninterrupted, or should I always assign a random name to my temporary files?

Comment: This is exactly what [`tmpfile()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tmpfile.php) is designed to do.

Comment: The requests are not executed one by one, they are executed in parallel and share the system's resources, make no assumptions as for the order in which the requests are executed!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They could very possibly be executed at the same time (in different threads).  You should always use a random name for temporary files.  The built in [tempnam](http://php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php) or [tmpfile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.tmpfile.php) functions make that pretty easy.

Answer (score 1):

It will depend on your web server. But in most cases I know of, there is no guarantee of the order in which requests will be served and for performance reasons many webservers are setup with multi-threading which does mean that two requests could be running parallel to each other.

You can check out the tempnam() function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php